# How to format a WinMerge fllter to ignore part of the line

Tags: regex, filter, winmerge

I would like WinMerge to compare the full text but exclude a variable substring.

```
Orientation="West" PhysicalAddress="2395226" DefFieldFrmt="Uf4d0" UnitCustomText="sec"
Orientation="West" PhysicalAddress="2395230" DefFieldFrmt="Uf4d1" UnitCustomText="sec"
```

In the lines above I want to ignore the PhysicalAddress="xxx" and locate the changed DefFieldFrmt="Uf4d1"

I have tried adding the filter:

```
PhysicalAddress=".*"
```

However this filters the complete line.

The actual text before and after the PhysicalAddress="xxx" will vary so I need a filter that says:  match prefix and match suffix but ignore target variable substring.

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Filters.html), is not possible to use the line filters for this:

> When a rule matches any part of the line, the entire difference is ignored. Therefore, you cannot filter just part of a line.

However, since WinMerge's source code is on GitHub, it is possible to add a feature request for this to its [list of issues](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/issues).